# Replace Android notification timestamp with Media Album in MediaStyle notification

Tags: android, notifications

I want to replace timestamp in MediaStyle notification but I don't know what MediaMetadata Key for this. What I want is put my string in that place, I used `putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, 'albumName')` but it not work.
[Please check this image for more detail about what I said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkIK5.png)

Thanks for helping

Comment: it is setSubText

Comment: You're right, should make your answer maybe can help others

Answer (score 0):

It is  called setSubText function.